# Pointer reference value can not be changed in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Rookie to C++ and can not understand the function passed by pointer and reference. Here is an example to describe the problem I meet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void getsincos( double x, double *&sinx, double *&cosx );

int main()
{
    double x = 30;
    double *sinx;
    double *cosx;

    getsincos( x, sinx, cosx );

    //cout << *sinx << endl;
    cout << *cosx << endl;

    return 0;
}

void getsincos( double x, double *&sinx, double *&cosx ){
    double temps, tempc;
    temps = sin( x );
    tempc = cos( x );
    sinx = &temps;
    cosx = &tempc;
    cout << *sinx << endl;
    cout << *cosx << endl;
}
```

I commented out the line `cout << *sinx << endl;`, the output is:

```
-0.988032
0.154251
0.154251
```

the first two come from the function definition and the last one comes from the main function. So next step, if I recovery the line `cout << *sinx << endl;`, the results are:

```
-0.988032
0.154251
-0.988032
6.95324e-310
```

definitely, the last one is wrong, it is an random number. Sorry that I do not find the error, could anyone give some explanation on it. Thanks.

Comment: You are taking the address of automatic variables. Automatic variables are destroyed when out of the scope.

Comment: Thanks @Daniele, so it means that I can only refer the function one time, otherwise, I need to run the function again?

Comment: I think you should study how things work in C++. There is a lot of leterature... and this is a very common problem.